# PHP Header authenticate not accepting User and Password

Tags: php, http, authentication, passwords

I am using the following PHP Authentication script for a site, but when I enter the user and password, the script won't accept them as correct (TEST/TEST1) and it always reloads the user/pass prompt (login function).

Here is my script.

```
function login()
{
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Acceso restringido."');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo "Acceso restringido.\n";
    exit;
}
if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
    login();
}
list($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'], $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']) = explode(':' , base64_decode(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'], 6)));

// open a user/pass prompt
if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
    login();
} else {
    if ($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] == 'TEST' && $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] == 'TEST1') {
   } else {
        login();
    }
}
```

Comment: `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` and $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] get populated automatically, it should not be needed to override them manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, it works fine for me:

```
session_start();
function login() {
    header("WWW-Authenticate: Basic"); 
    header("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");
    die; 
}
if (!isset($_SESSION["AUTH_SUCCESS"])) {
    $_SESSION["AUTH_SUCCESS"] = 0;
}
if ($_SESSION["AUTH_SUCCESS"] == 0) {
    $user = "TEST"; 
    $pass = "TESTPASS";
    if ($_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_USER"] != $user || $_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_PW"] != $pass) { 
        login();
    } else {
        $_SESSION["AUTH_SUCCESS"] = 1;
    }
}
if ($_SESSION["AUTH_SUCCESS"] == 0) {
    die("You have entered a wrong password/username.");
}
```

This code holds a variable in session named AUTH_SUCCESS, as long this variable is 0 (Zero) then the prompt will appear, when the user enters the user/pass, then the variable value will become 1 and the prompt will stop appearing.

Comment: Tested it, but same thing. It re-prompts the user/pass box